# How to pass function from Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I am using react navigation v4. I have there a DrawerNavigator with components of three buttons suppose each button dispatch a function in specific page

I am trying a lot how to pass those functions ( if it's possible ) to desired page so I can clare function in the page and when button in the drawer is pressed fire this function

```
const SettingDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    TaskEdit : {
        screen : TaskEditScreen,
        navigationOptions : {
            title : 'Settings',
        },
    },
} , {
   drawerPosition : 'right',
   defaultNavigationOptions : defaultNavOptions,
   contentOptions : {
    activeTintColor : Colors.primary
   },
   contentComponent : (props) =>  <View style = {{marginVertical : 10}}>
      <Button 
      title = 'Set as Done' onPress = {props.done}
        titleStyle  = {{color : 'white' , fontFamily : 'header'}}
        buttonStyle = {{
            backgroundColor : Colors.primary,
            width : '80%',
            marginVertical : 10,
            alignSelf : 'center'
        }}
        icon ={ <Ionicons
        name = {Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-done-all' : 'ios-done-all'}
        size = {23}
        color  = 'white'
        style = {{marginRight : 20}}
        />}
        iconContainerStyle = {{marginRight : 10}}
        />
         <Button title = 'Close Task' onPress = {() => props.navigation.navigate('Reminders')}
            titleStyle  = {{color : 'white' , fontFamily : 'header'}}
            buttonStyle = {{
                backgroundColor : Colors.primary,
                width : '80%',
                marginVertical : 10,
                alignSelf : 'center'
            }}
            icon = {
                <Ionicons
                name = {Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-close' : 'ios-close'}
                size = {23}
                color  = 'white'
                style = {{marginRight : 20}}
                />
            }
            iconContainerStyle = {{marginRight : 10}}
            />
            <Button 
            {...props}
            title = 'Cancel' onPress = {() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer(
            )} 
                titleStyle  = {{color : 'white' , fontFamily : 'header'}}
                buttonStyle = {{
                    backgroundColor : Colors.primary,
                    width : '80%',
                    marginVertical : 10,
                    alignSelf : 'center'
                }}
            />
   </View>
})
```

Comment: you want to set params to your screen ?

Comment: No I want to pass a props

Comment: Don't fully understand what you want you have 3 buttons but what you want to pass and where exactly in your code you only navigate. You want to navigate to Reminders and pass props ?

Comment: Sorry for being confusing I know that I am confusing you 

Comment: What I need is like what we are doing in parent/children components. for example (props.close) be passed so in the page contains drawer navigator I can do something like close={myFunction). Accordingly when user open the drawer and press close it will perform a close functiom that I will clare there

Comment: Hope now I can deliver what I need

Comment: so from your custom contentComponent you want to pass a function to your 3 buttons to execute that functions in that screens or the reverse from children screens to contentComponent(father)?.

Comment: first option from my custom contentComponent Iwant to pass a function to my 3 buttons to execute that functions in that screens